# How do you configure AWS cloudfront to use SSL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We are using cloudfront to serve images with a custom domain.

```
http://images.example.com/fubar.png
```

We want to be able to access them with SSL, eg `https://images.example.com/fubar.png`

We have a wildcard SSL certificate (issued from Godaddy) for `*.example.com` and I used the **AWS Certificate Manager** to upload the certificate, private key, and keychain.  The upload appears to have been successful as `*.example.com` appears to be **issued** (according to the Certificate Manager).

How do I "apply" this wildcard SSL to `images.example.com`?  If I visit **CloudFront Distributions** and edit the General settings to select **Custom SSL Certificate** I can see my `*.example.com` wildcard SSL.  But when I try to click the **Yes, Edit** button I get the following error message:

> com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidViewerCertificateException: The specified SSL certificate doesn't exist, isn't in us-east-1 region, isn't valid, or doesn't include a valid certificate chain. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate; Request ID: ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff)

What steps do I need to take to allow me to apply this Wldcard SSL cert to my cloudfront images with custom DNS name?

Comment: I think you can generate SSL certificate in AWS Certificate Manager. Is there any specific reason for not using AWS certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot say for sure, but typically with issues like this your certificate chain is incorrect. You’ll need to check the certificate authority’s instructions for creating the chain (e.g. what intermediate certificates does it need).

Comment: Is there a way of getting the certificate chain from another server that is successfully using the SSL certificate?

Comment: I'm getting a different error now, but I think I have the certificate chain uploaded properly

Comment: Hey @WhiskerBiscuit. Did you get this resolved in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, and finally found out it's the `the maximum size of the public key in an SSL/TLS certificate` issue.
AWS CloudFront only support 2048 bits, although Certificate Manager allows you to import 4096 bit keys.

Please refer to:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-size-of-public-key.html

**Especially this one**: step by step
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-requirements.html#https-requirements-certificate-format